# How to add multiple text search in mongo full text search using pymonog

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have monogo collection with column name server_name an dos_name like below.

[image]

i have added index on server_name

```
db.createIndex({"server_name":"text"})
```

I want to search the record in with server name "Apple Mac pro" and "Cisco USB Mini"

I have tried below query.

```
db.collection_name.find({"$text": {"$search": '"Apple Mac Pro" "Cisco UCS Mini"'}});
```

but it giving blank result.

I have tried different different approaches like and multiple text search but want work.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for what you're describing you should just use `$in` with an exact match:

```
db.collection_name.find({ server_name: { $in: ['Apple Mac Pro', 'Cisco UCS Mini'] } });
```

Assuming you do really want a `$text` search then you have to execute two separate calls, due to the `$text` [restrictions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions)

> A query can specify, at most, one $text expression.

> If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase.

Essentially two phrases execute `$and` logic between them, and because you can only execute a single `$text` query you need to split it into 2 calls.

Comment: thank you, but if I split the search in 2 calls then it will affect my performance right.?

Comment: Yes, depending on your scale this could be negligent